# Epic Games Launcher crashing on MacOS

Tags: macos, crash

Have tried everything from deleting related files to reinstalling the launcher and MacOS on a new partition. Crashes on every launch. Epic can't help since they "don't have a MacOS developer".

I've found one workaround. If I disconnect from WiFi and launch the app, it will launch successfully ( and automatically log me out ). I can then login and use it normally. If I quit again and try to relaunch, it continues to crash.

Anyone have a solution?

Edit: Seems to be fixed as of 21/12/2022.

Comment: Thank you for this work around.  Facing the same issue now (MBP 2019, OSX 11.2.2, and latest Epic Client 12.1.6)

Answer (score 12):

I turn WIFI off, then open the app, and it lunches.
Then turn on WIFI and login.

Comment: seems like it crashes while signing into epic account.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was going to Library>App Support>Epic

And just deleting the whole Epic folder then launching the app again.

Answer (score -1):

Same deal here, I downloaded it today and it crashed on opening. I followed these steps from the epic site and it fixed the issue for me.

Mac

- Exit the Epic Games Launcher.
- Open Finder.
- Click on Go then Go to Folder...
- Type ~/Library/Caches/com.epicgames.EpicGamesLauncher and press Enter.
- Drag the webcache folder to the Trash.
- Press control and click on Trash.
- Click on Empty Trash.
- Relaunch the Epic Games Launcher.